# How to add nofollow attribute on CKEditor when modify post

Tags: html, ckeditor

I'm using [CKEditor 4.5.5](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/releases/tag/4.5.5) version.

I add the next code for adding nofollow.

It working fine and stored my DB. but, when I modify the post, CKEditor `auto-removed ref="nofollow"` attributes.

How can I loading origin attributes on CKEditor?

-- Write page. add nofollow code --

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function () {
    CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
        var editor = ev.editor;
        editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
            elements: {
                a: function (element) {
                    if (!element.attributes.rel)
                        element.attributes.rel = 'nofollow';
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is fine. but it seems like there is an extra plugins, definitions and/or settings that allow very specific attributes on elements, and automatically removed this attribute, since it is not specifically allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify file `ckeditor_config.js`.
Add following code:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'a[rel]';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this `link` config in javascript create code:

```
var myeditor;
    ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#myeditor'), {
        toolbar: {
            items: [
                'link',
                ...
            ]
        },
        link: {
            decorators: {
                toggleDownloadable: {
                    mode: 'manual',
                    label: 'Downloadable',
                    attributes: {
                        download: 'file'
                    }
                },
                openInNewTab: {
                    mode: 'manual',
                    label: 'Open in a new tab',
                    defaultValue: true,
                    attributes: {
                        target: '_blank',
                        rel: 'noopener'
                    }
                },
                addNofollow: {
                    mode: 'manual',
                    label: 'Add Nofollow rel',
                    attributes: {
                        target: '_blank',
                        rel: 'noopener nofollow'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    })
    .then(edt => {
        ...
    })
    .catch(error => {
        ..
});
```